# How can I find a Nebula Arcanum?

Tags: terraria

I found out that this new weapon can help me defeat the Moon Lord on PC. I've looked on the wiki, but can't find any info on this weapon. How do you get one?

Comment: You looked at the wiki on this item but couldn't find any information about the item?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The [Nebula Arcanum](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nebula_Arcanum) is crafted out of 18 Nebula Fragments at an Ancient Manipulator. Nebula Fragments are obtained by destroying the Nebula Pillar, which spawns after defeating the Lunatic Cultist.

Comment: how do i get the fragments

Comment: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nebula_Fragment

Comment: @coolgamerq I refuse to believe you haven't found any fragments if you're trying to fight the Moon Lord

Comment: are the fragments after the moon lord?

Comment: @coolgamerq Even a cursory amount of research shows that the Moon Lord is considered the hardest boss at this time. That shows no effort has been made to find out any of this yourself.

Comment: i reread the post and i now realize that i have to destroy the nebula pillars to get the fragments